# Fastest way to create thousands of unique objects

Tags: python, scripting, objects

**Question**

How to add thousands of (actually more or less 100,000) unique objects in a reasonable amount of time (meaning that there is none or less increase of computation time per object). With unique I mean that I calculate the vertices for every object in dependence of two nested loops.

**Problem**

The amount of time needed for creation increases exponentially which is still acceptably for a few thousand objects but gets worse after these. So, my script has not even finished creating these objects (with less than 10 vertices each) after 48h running.

**Details**

At the moment I use "the data method" described [here in the Blender wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Three_ways_to_create_objects) to create the objects which should be more effective than the "operator method" or "primitive method". Even if I remove the `.update()`, `.link` and `.active` calls (for testing purpose), the time still increases exponentially. I don't know which other call causes this time increase or if there is another reason for it.

Due to the nature of the problem, a speedup of a factor of 2 or even 10 will not help much as at some later iteration the computation time is still be incredable large.

How can I, if even possible, create objects without this time increase by interation?

**Code snippets**

```
def createMeshFromData(name, origin, verts, faces):
    me = bpy.data.meshes.new(name+'Mesh')
    ob = bpy.data.objects.new(name, me)
    scn = bpy.context.scene
    #scn.objects.link(ob)           #needed but commented for test purpose
    #scn.objects.active = ob        #needed but commented for test purpose
    me.from_pydata(verts, [], faces)
    #me.update()                    #not needed for my purpose
    return ob

def createObj(name, Verts, params): #Verts: list of Vectors
    for i in range(Verts):
        Verts[i] = #modify vertices according params
    ob = createMeshFromData('Obj', Vector((0,0,0)), Verts, faces)
    return ob
```

Comment: Python and the blender api has a huge overhead. This overhead is the num of calls and data transformation between c structures and python objects. This can only be reduced by using c.

Comment: Can you eloborate this? I would see a "It is not possible this way" as an answer, too. However, could other approaches be a solution, something like: array modifier -> separate -> modify, or create one object with all the vertices -> separate by loose parts? Or saving the project halfways and continuing calculation within the restarted file?

Comment: Check here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgJKmspCQMIivIdce4P_v4uqCh0f93tax I'm not familiar with NumPY but as stated by creator of this tutorial series it's way faster than regular python scripts.